# Xamarin missing directive

Tags: xamarin

Can anyone help me what I am missing to run xamarin app?
Part of code where error is:

```
 switch (Build.VERSION.SdkInt)
                    {
                        case >= BuildVersionCodes.Q:
                            object p = context.Window?.SetDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);

                    }
```

Output message:

> 1>F:\Programi\Visual Studio\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(427,3): warning XA0119: Using fast deployment and the linker at the same time is not recommended. Use fast deployment for Debug configurations and the linker for Release configurations.
> 1>C:\Users\ognje\Desktop\21\QuickDate_V1.9\QuickDate\Gc_Collecter.txt : warning XA0101: @(Content) build action is not supported
> 1>F:\Programi\Visual Studio\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2182,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.CSharp" that could not be resolved.
> 1>F:\Programi\Visual Studio\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2182,5): warning MSB3277: There was a conflict between "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
> 1>F:\Programi\Visual Studio\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2182,5): warning MSB3277:     "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
> 1>F:\Programi\Visual Studio\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2182,5): warning MSB3277:     References which depend on "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [F:\Programi\Visual Studio\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll].
> 1>F:\Programi\Visual Studio\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2182,5): warning MSB3277:         F:\Programi\Visual Studio\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll
> 1>F:\Programi\Visual Studio\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2182,5): warning MSB3277:           Project file item includes which caused reference "F:\Programi\Visual Studio\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll".
> 1>F:\Programi\Visual Studio\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2182,5): warning MSB3277:             Microsoft.CSharp
> 1>F:\Programi\Visual Studio\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2182,5): warning MSB3277:     References which depend on "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [].
> 1>F:\Programi\Visual Studio\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2182,5): warning MSB3277:         C:\Users\ognje.nuget\packages\automapper\10.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\AutoMapper.dll
> 1>F:\Programi\Visual Studio\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2182,5): warning MSB3277:           Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\ognje.nuget\packages\automapper\10.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\AutoMapper.dll".
> 1>F:\Programi\Visual Studio\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2182,5): warning MSB3277:             C:\Users\ognje.nuget\packages\automapper\10.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\AutoMapper.dll
> 1>C:\Users\ognje.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.10.0\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(88,3): warning XBD100: ItemGroup `XamarinBuildDownloadRestoreAssemblyAar` is no longer supported.  If your build is failing, revert to an older Xamarin.Build.Download version, or migrate your packages to use the new `XamarinBuildDownloadAndroidAarLibrary` ItemGroup.  If your build is succeeding it is safe to ignore this warning.
> 1>C:\Users\ognje\Desktop\21\QuickDate_V1.9\QuickDate\Helpers\Utils\Methods.cs(2536,59,2536,85): error CS1061: 'Window' does not contain a definition for 'SetDecorFitsSystemWindows' and no accessible extension method 'SetDecorFitsSystemWindows' accepting a first argument of type 'Window' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: that method was added in API 30.  Which API are you targeting?

Comment: API 29 is mine target api

Comment: if it was added in 30 you can't use it in 29

Comment: ok, every single error I had are gone, but new one arrived:
java.exe exited with code 1

Comment: you need to look at the logs for other error messages

Comment: Your target SDK is probably still lower than 30, which is why it isn't finding it.